# Starting another activity from onCreate gives me blank screen

Tags: java, android, start-activity

Basically when I start the `SignInActivity` from the `MainActivity` it gives me the `Activity` label at the top, but then the rest of the screen is blank. I don't know if it has to do with my `XML` layout or what but I don't get any errors or anything. Another weird thing is that when I put a `Log.e()` in the `SignInActivity` it never logs anything... weird

```
 // OnCreate // ActivityMain
 //check prefs for the update on authenticatedGoogleAccount and staysignedin
    boolean authenticatedGoogleAccount = prefs.getBoolean("authenticatedGoogle_key", false);
    boolean staysignedin_isChecked = prefs.getBoolean("staysignedin_key",false);

    if(!authenticatedGoogleAccount || !staysignedin_isChecked){
        Intent e = new Intent(MainMenu_Activity.this,SignIn_Activity.class);
        startActivity(e);
    }

// OnCreate // SignInActivity
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signin_page);
    Log.e("Hello from signin", "");
    verify_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verify_button);
    signin_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin_button);

    link4help = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

    gmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signin_email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signin_password);

    email_success = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.email_authenticate_success);
    password_success = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.password_authenticate_success);

    email_success.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    password_success.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    signin_button.setEnabled(false);

    verify_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    signin_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    link4help.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

--

```
//xml file from SignInActivity//
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <!-- Header Starts  -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip">

            <!-- Logo Start -->

            <TextView
                android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionSignin"
                android:text="@string/WelcometoDictaShare"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
            <!-- Logo Ends -->
     </LinearLayout>
     <!-- Header Ends -->

     <!-- Footer Start -->
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="80dip"
         android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
     </LinearLayout>                
     <!-- Footer Ends -->

     <!-- Login Form -->
     <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dip"
      android:layout_below="@id/header">

     <!-- ACCOUNT SIGN IN -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingTop="15dp" 
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"         
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="@string/account_title"/>
      <EditText  android:id="@+id/signin_account_name"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:hint="@string/signin_hint"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:minHeight="20dp"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@layout/borderedittext"/>

      <LinearLayout android:background="@layout/border"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="10dp">

           <!-- Google LOGO -->
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:contentDescription="@string/googlelogo"
          android:gravity="right"
          android:layout_gravity="right"
          android:src="@drawable/googlelogo" />


      <!--  Email Label -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="@string/Email"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:weightSum="1">
          <EditText  android:id="@+id/signin_email"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:background="@layout/borderedittext"/>

          <ImageView android:id="@+id/email_authenticate_success"
              android:src="@drawable/navigation_accept"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:contentDescription="@string/authenticationsuccess"
              android:layout_weight=".5"
              />
      </LinearLayout>
      <!--  Password Label -->


      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="@string/Password"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:weightSum="1">

          <EditText android:id="@+id/signin_password"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:background="@layout/borderedittext"/>

          <ImageView android:id="@+id/password_authenticate_success"
                  android:src="@drawable/navigation_accept"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:contentDescription="@string/authenticationsuccess"
                  android:layout_weight=".5"
                  />
      </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="1">

          <!-- Authentication button -->
          <Button android:id="@+id/verify_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="@string/verify"
                android:background="@layout/borderbuttonverify"
                android:layout_weight=".1"/>
          <!-- Link to Registration Screen -->
          <TextView android:id="@+id/link_to_register"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:text="@string/cantaccessyouracccount"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#4d8ffc"
                android:layout_weight=".9"/>
          </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>  


       <LinearLayout
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="1"
               android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

          <Button android:id="@+id/signin_button"
                android:background="#4d8ffc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/signin"
                android:layout_weight=".5"/>

          <CheckBox android:id="@+id/staysignedin"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
              android:layout_weight=".5"
              android:text="@string/staysignedin"/>

       </LinearLayout>
     <!-- Login Form Ends -->
     </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is all the code at the top in?

Comment: Did you set the content view on your 2nd Activity?!!!

Comment: Does your `SignInActvity extends Activity`?

Comment: To work around this for now I just changed my scrollview to a relative view and it is working. @tycz the code at the top is in my first activity (check the comments), which calls the second one (SignInActivity).

Comment: @IronBlossom yes......

Answer (score 0):

I tried your .xml in my code (structured much like yours), and since I didn't have the drawing or string resources, I substituted plain text for your strings, used white for all backgrounds, and removed the src references for imageview.  The only thing I did in OnCreate for the signin_activity was the setcontentview to signin_page.xml.  When called like this, your page comes up with all the text fields.  Based on that, my guess would be either the xml isn't being matched by name from your SetContentView call, or maybe there's a problem with the src links in the ImageViews.
Like you, I didn't get the Log.e with your string, but I changed it to this Log.e("SigninActivity","Hello from signin"), and it worked (maybe Log doesn't like spaces in the first parameter?)
HTH

p.s. and related - there's not an ending ScrollView tag in the code you have posted